# When I am trying to drop tables using below script , it seems not working.

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ddl

I am trying to drop tables from each server. My Server 1 has 3 Databases and Server 2 has 6 and Server 3 has 8.

Below is the SQL Script that I wrote to perform the drop operation from each databases in in particular server. After I perform these operation.

```
DECLARE
   @LoopId     int,
   @Command    varchar(500),
   @tblName varchar(100)

DECLARE @List TABLE
(
   TableName  sysname  not null,
   LoopId     int      not null  identity(1,1)
)

--  Load with tables you wish to drop

INSERT @List (TableName)

SELECT name FROM [Morgage].sys.objects WHERE type = 'u' and name like '%JKL%'
SELECT name FROM [Scorecard].sys.objects WHERE type = 'u'and name like '%JKL%'
SELECT name FROM [Core].sys.objects WHERE type = 'u' and name like '%JKL%'

SET @LoopId = @@rowcount

--  Go through list and process each item
WHILE @LoopId > 0

BEGIN

SET @tblName = (SELECT TableName from @List where LoopId = @LoopId)    
SET @Command = 'Drop table ' + @tblName

execute (@Command)

SET @LoopId = @LoopId - 1
END
```

Above query result says rows affected but then when i go and try to test is using below query. I do see everything. What my query did actually? Am I doing it right?

```
SELECT name FROM [Scorecard].sys.objects WHERE type = 'u'and name like '%JKL%'
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Two things jump out at me. The value of `@@ROWCOUNT` will be the number of rows affected from your last select statement. You need to capture and accumulate the row count otherwise you will miss everything after that LoopId. Secondly, you aren't changing the database when you execute the dynamically generated SQL, so you could potentially be dropping objects from the wrong database.

Comment: Apologies, just re-read your script - you are using SQL 2008 then

Comment: Missed the multiple line insert... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version of your script:-

```
DECLARE
   @LoopId     int,
   @Command    varchar(500),
   @tblName varchar(100),
   @dbName sysname


DECLARE @List TABLE
(
   DBName sysname not null,
   TableName  sysname  not null,
   LoopId     int      not null  identity(1,1)
)

--  Load with tables you wish to drop

INSERT @List (DBName, TableName)

SELECT 'Morgage',name FROM [Morgage].sys.objects WHERE type = 'u' and name like '%JKL%'
UNION
SELECT 'Scorecard',name FROM [Scorecard].sys.objects WHERE type = 'u'and name like '%JKL%'
UNION
SELECT 'Core',name FROM [Core].sys.objects WHERE type = 'u' and name like '%JKL%'

SET @LoopId = @@rowcount

--  Go through list and process each item
WHILE @LoopId > 0

BEGIN

SELECT @tblName = TableName, @dbName=DBName from @List where LoopId = @LoopId

SET @Command = 'USE ' + @dbName + ';if not exists(select 1 from sys.foreign_keys where parent_object_id=object_id(''' + @tblName + ''',''U'')' + char(10) + 'Drop table ' + @tblName + ';'

execute (@Command)

SET @LoopId = @LoopId - 1
END
```

Comment: Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.      ** This is what I get the error

Comment: Edited the answer - I had forgotten to add DBName field into the field list for the INSERT statement. Sorry.

Comment: I tried running query. But it gives me result of the table name from Scorecard only.?

Comment: Try putting a `select * from @List` in the query to see exactly what it is trying to drop. It may also be worth putting a `print @Command` after, or in place of, the execute(@Command) statement

Comment: I am trying to test it again. It only took one statement drop tables from that Morgage DB.  It didn't do anything with others.

Comment: I have edited the asnwer to use `UNION` when inserting into `@List`. That should do it.

Comment: I had a question. What about dependencies ? if one table has a foreign key that is reference to an another table in the database? Do i have to change any code? Because I tried to do with another db and it gives me error that i can't drop that object because it is referenced by foreign key constraints. :-( please help me out

Comment: Indeed you can't drop a table that has FK constraints into it. You could wrap the `DROP` in an `IF` to see if there are foreign jeys into the table you are trying to drop (answer will be edited shortly)

Comment: I am trying to run. it gives me some error near by end of the statement that you have edited and near by 'U'

Comment: Looks like I have missed an opening quote in front of the `DROP` statement - answer edited

Comment: It says still an error near by U :-( I tried to play with it. But unable to solve it.

Comment: @maina - sorry, just logged back in. Needed another quote on each side of the U (asnwer updated)

Answer (score 0):

Might be the queries are not committing by default. Try specify it explicitly